# "Duplicate definition of column" error while updating schema

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My bundle use FOSUserBundle Entity. But I need set password nullable = true for my bundle 
how to set this in my bundle entity. when I put the password in my user entity and update schema then getting 
duplicate error. Please help me

Comment: This approach feels not secure, did you think about generating a random password instead of leaving it empty?